# Logistic regression with proportions in R (dependent variable is not binary). What is R doing?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

So I stumbled across the following code:

```
#Importing the data:
seeds.df <- 
read.table('http://www.uib.no/People/nzlkj/statkey/data/seeds.csv',header=T)
attach(seeds.df)

#Making a plot of seeds eaten depending on seed type:
plot(Seed.type, Eaten)

#Testing the hypothesis:
fit1.glm <- glm(cbind(Eaten,Not.eaten)~Seed.type, binomial)
summary(fit1.glm)
```

From https://folk.uib.no/nzlkj/statkey/logistic.html#proportions

which provides a method for doing logistic regression on proportion data.

My question is what is R actually doing mathematically? the response variable is two columns. As far as I knew logistic regression is supposed to be performed on binary dependent variable.

is R creating a new response variable of length Eaten + Not.eaten 
which is populated by rep(1, Eaten) rep(0, Not.eaten) and performing log regression on that?

e.g. for row 1 in seeds.df Eaten = 2 Not.eaten = 48

```
row#    eaten.or.not    seed.type    Hamster
1        1                 B            1
2        1                 B            1
3        0                 B            1
         0                 B            1 
     ...                  
50       0                 B            1
```

then R would do glm(eaten.or.not ~ seed.type, family = 'binomial')

I tested the above and it didn't produce the same answer

or is R doing the following

ln(prob of being eaten/ (1-prob of being eaten)) = intercept + B1(seed.type)

I also tested this and I got something different, but I'm not sure I did it correctly.

Anyway, could someone shed light on what R is doing mathematically for the log regression with a proportion that would be great.

thank you for your time

Comment: What do you mean by, it did not produce the same answer? I copy pasted the code from the site you linked to and it produced almost the same output. (Degrees of freedom and deviances were the same, p-value was different but this is probably some changes in anova, the models should be the same if the deviances are the same. Still interesting why the p-value changees.)

Comment: What I think that R does internally is just fit a logistic-regression to the proportions data. This is possible, because it is just a generalized linear model with a link function. It is not accurate thoug because logit is the link function for odds, probit would be the link function for proportions.